# Method used in t.test()

Tags: r, t-test

The results of a `t.test()` in R provide a parameter `$method` which seems to be always equal to `Welch Two Sample t-test` which corrects for unequal variances. Are there other methods used in this function other than Welch's? I have looked in the documentation of the stats package in the CRAN repository but have not been able to find the source code for the `t.test` function nor information about `t.test$method`. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you set `var.equal = TRUE`, then you will get the usual Student test without Welch's correction of the degrees of freedom. Similarly, if you run a one-sample t test or a paired t test, you will get different strings.

Here is the secret on how to see source code written in R. (Source code written in C, C++ or Fortran is another story).

Run `methods(t.test)`. You will get the following output:

`t.test.default* t.test.formula*`

The `*` means that the method is hidden and not exported from its package (`stats` in this case). You can access it via `stats:::t.test.default` and you will get the code.

Comment: Thanks for the secret. I am doing an F-test to determine whether the variances are equal and calculating the degrees of freedom accordingly. I am not using the t.test function but getting the p-values from pt(). It was tempting to let t.test() do the calculations but needed to be sure what was going on. Thanks for this very valuable information.